# How to add multiple files/Images to a SQL Server database using C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, file, http

I am trying to save multiple files using the following method, the files reach the API but when I try to hit the save method, saving to the db, only the first file is saved.

```
using (DatabaseContextOE db = new DatabaseContextOE())
{
    db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;

    var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;

    foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
    {
        tblFile attachmentFile = new tblFile();

        var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];

        BinaryReader binReader = new BinaryReader(postedFile.InputStream);
        byteArray = binReader.ReadBytes(postedFile.ContentLength);

        if (byteArray == null)
        {
            response.Status = ResponseStatus.Failure;
            response.StatusDescription = "No file has been selected";
        }
        else
        {
            attachmentFile.OrderID = iIncidentID;
            attachmentFile.cFileName = postedFile.FileName;
            attachmentFile.cFileType = postedFile.ContentType;
            attachmentFile.cFileImage = byteArray;

            db.tblFile.Add(attachmentFile);
            db.SaveChanges();

            response.Status = ResponseStatus.Success;
            response.StatusDescription = "File uploaded successfully";
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: saving images in databses cost performance, so if there is no good reason, why not save only the file names and the file i a drive

Comment: Yes dont save binary files to the database, put them on a file server, azure blob storage and store the url in the database instead

Answer (score 0):

You can only add one file, becvause your response is insede the if clasue,, but it must be send only after the file are all updated and that os when the for loop has ended

```
using (DatabaseContextOE db = new DatabaseContextOE())
{
    db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;

    var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;

    foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
    {
        tblFile attachmentFile = new tblFile();

        var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];

        BinaryReader binReader = new BinaryReader(postedFile.InputStream);
        byteArray = binReader.ReadBytes(postedFile.ContentLength);

        if (byteArray == null)
        {
            response.Status = ResponseStatus.Failure;
            response.StatusDescription = "No file has been selected";
        }
        else
        {
            attachmentFile.OrderID = iIncidentID;
            attachmentFile.cFileName = postedFile.FileName;
            attachmentFile.cFileType = postedFile.ContentType;
            attachmentFile.cFileImage = byteArray;

            db.tblFile.Add(attachmentFile);
            db.SaveChanges();

        }
    }
    response.Status = ResponseStatus.Success;
    response.StatusDescription = "File uploaded successfully";
}
```